# md RAID spare disk partition has another partition?

Tags: partitioning, raid, mdadm

I recently had a drive fail in my RAID 5 array with 3 disks and 1 spare. The spare was used automatically. All seems to be working OK.

I then added a new disk as the new spare like this, where `sdb` was a working drive in the array and `sdc` is the new one as reported by `dmesg`:

`sfdisk -d /dev/sdb | sfdisk /dev/sdc`

`mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdc1`

However, becuase I forgot to add the parition number on that last command, it means the partitioning scheme isn't the same for the spare as it is the others, and `/proc/mdstat` looks like this now:

```
md0 : active raid5 sdc[4](S) sdd1[5] sdb1[3] sde1[6]
      955537408 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 0/4 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

`lsblk` shows this:

```
sdb                         8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                      8:17   0 455.8G  0 part  
  └─md0                     9:0    0 911.3G  0 raid5 /mnt/nas
sdc                         8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sdc1                      8:33   0 455.8G  0 part  
└─md0                       9:0    0 911.3G  0 raid5 /mnt/nas
sdd                         8:48   0 465.8G  0 disk  
└─sdd1                      8:49   0 455.8G  0 part  
  └─md0                     9:0    0 911.3G  0 raid5 /mnt/nas
sde                         8:64   0 465.8G  0 disk  
└─sde1                      8:65   0 455.8G  0 part  
  └─md0                     9:0    0 911.3G  0 raid5 /mnt/nas
```

Is it a problem that the spare disk is different in the event that it needs to be added? Should I remove it and re-add it so that it's the same?

Comment: RAID 5 is supposed to have the parity striped across the disks and not have a spare.  While you can use it with a spare, it is better to have the parity striped.  You probably need to grow your array to 4 disks.  See:  https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Growing

Comment: You're right, but I'm just too lazy to reconfigure the RAID for that. The existence of the spare is because originally I only had 3 disks and bought another one later :-)

Comment: Then nothing is wrong the way it is configured.  As long as it is mounting correctly then there is no issue.  If you have rebooted the host from the time the one drive went bad and installed your new hot spare, the `/dev/sdX` can change between reboots.  As far as I remember the RAID is created by the UUID and not the `/dev/sdXX` anyways.  Then it should be mounted in the `fstab` file by the UUID.  If you look in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` you should be able to see your ARRAYs in there using the UUIDs instead of the drive designations.

Comment: If you run `sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0` it should show you the health (state) of your array, the ARRAY UUID and the drives that are currently in use for the array.

Comment: Oh OK. So it'll just use the UUID of the partition I added for the spare. `mdadm -D` looks fine.